# Jquery .on change() hitting both all select fields in js.erb file ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Javascript and Jquery in Rails so apologies if something like this has been asked before. I have been stuck on this issue all day now. 
I have three fields in a form, "from location," "to location," and "quantity". When the "from location" select field is changed, I'd like for:

- the "to location," to change to remove the selected field in the "from location"
- the "quantity" to reflect the available quantity at the "from location."

I am writing this in my edit.js.erb file for my item model.

I have given all fields different classes and am referencing the specific field by class but the .on change() is firing for all select fields.

(The variable fohInventoryItems is provided via a script block in this model's index page.)
Here's my code:

```js
var selectedItemClass = <%=@item.id%>


(document).on('change', $('select.' + selectedItemClass + "." + 'from-select').eq(0), function() {

  });
```

And her is my code in _form.html.erb for this model:

```
<%= form_for item, remote: true, format: "js" do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :from_location %><br>
      <%= f.collection_select :location_ids, item.locations.uniq, :id, :name, {selected: item.locations.uniq.first}, { class: "form-control #{item.id} from-select", }  %><br>

    <%= fields_for :line_items, item.line_items.build do |l| %>

        <%= l.label :to_location %><br>
        <%= l.collection_select :location, Location.all, :id, :name, {}, { class: "form-control #{item.id} to-select" }  %><br>


        <%= f.label :quantity %><br>
        <%= f.select :quantity, (Array (1..item.quantity)), {}, { class: "form-control #{item.id}" }  %>

    <%end%>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <%= f.submit "Move", class: "#{item.id} submit" %><br>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `on()` as a delegated event handler, the second argument is used as a filter internally to check if the elements match a selector.

The documentation clearly states that the syntax is

```
.on( events [, selector ] , handler )
```

With `seleector` being

> **selector**
>   Type: String
>
> A selector string to filter the descendants of
>   the selected elements that will call the handler. If the selector is
>   null or omitted, the handler is always called when it reaches the
>   selected element.

The reason for it being a string, is that the elements will be checked against it, so it can't be another jQuery collection.

...meaning you have to change your code to

```
$(document).on('change', '.' + selectedItemClass + 'from-select', function() {...
```